# issue with dc.ChoroplethChart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

This is the code for displaying a choropleth chart using dc.js and crossfilter. The chart is not getting displayed instead a blank square is displayed with only one region data. I want to get a complete graph with all regions data.I even tried using different projection functions and even tried removing .projection, .colordomain but nothing workedout. Infoviz1.geojson(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iC_BAOnkqhjw-wZJ-jDiKiuhxIDMBp9N/view?usp=sharing)
NewData.csv(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LcOn3R__ig37U4Us2UoIJZAhyA05NweY/view?usp=sharing)
. Please help me.

```
  var CanadaChart = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#canada-chart");
 queue()
 .defer(d3.csv, "NewData.csv")
 .defer(d3.json, "infoviz1.geojson")
 .await(makeGraphs);
 function makeGraphs(error, url, url2json) {
        
        var data = url;
        console.log(url2json["features"]);
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Episode_week = +d["Episode_week"];

        });

        
        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        
        // Dimensions declaration
      
        var CanadaDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["Region"];}); 
        console.log(CanadaDim.top(Infinity))
      
        // Groups Metrics
     
        var CanadaGroup = CanadaDim.group().reduceCount();
        console.log(CanadaGroup.top(Infinity));
        

        CanadaChart
          .width(110)
          .height(250)
          .dimension(CanadaDim)
          .group(CanadaGroup)

          .colors(["#edf8fb", "#b2e2e2", "#66c2a4", "#2ca25f", "#006d2c"])
          .colorDomain([612, 20000])
         
          .overlayGeoJson(url2json.features,"State", function (p) { 
             console.log(p.properties.name)
             return p.properties.name;
          })
          .projection(d3.geo.albers()
                 .scale(300).center([0, 60])
                   .translate([350, 200]))
          

          .title(function (d) {
              
               return "Region: " + d["key"]
            + "\n"
            + "TotalCases" + Math.round(d["value"]) ;
          });
```

---

This is my customized geojson file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Region5"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-122.958984375,49.210420445650286],[-114.43359375,49.15296965617042],[-114.9609375,50.28933925329178],[-120.0146484375,53.85252660044951],[-119.970703125,60.06484046010452],[-123.57421875,60.06484046010452],[-126.21093749999999,60.84491057364912],[-130.95703125,64.24459476798195],[-133.9453125,67.03316279015063],[-135.966796875,67.03316279015063],[-136.23046875,68.9110048456202],[-141.15234374999997,69.71810669906763],[-141.50390625,60.19615576604439],[-134.560546875,58.44773280389084],[-129.90234375,53.904338156274704],[-127.44140625,51.890053935216926],[-122.958984375,49.210420445650286]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Region4"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-135.87890625,68.97416358340674],[-136.0546875,67.16995497083367],[-133.9453125,67.03316279015063],[-126.5625,60.88770004207789],[-123.662109375,60.108670463036],[-119.970703125,60.02095215374802],[-119.970703125,53.9560855309879],[-114.873046875,50.3454604086048],[-114.521484375,49.210420445650286],[-95.09765625,48.980216985374994],[-95.2734375,52.96187505907603],[-88.330078125,56.9449741808516],[-92.373046875,57.040729838360875],[-95.09765625,60.06484046010452],[-102.041015625,59.93300042374631],[-101.77734374999999,64.20637724320852],[-108.720703125,64.73664139557683],[-109.599609375,65.44000165965534],[-112.8515625,65.62202261510642],[-120.673828125,67.7760253890732],[-120.673828125,69.62651016802958],[-123.04687499999999,69.41124235697256],[-125.94726562499999,69.53451763078358],[-127.96875,70.05059634999759],[-135.87890625,68.97416358340674]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Region3"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.71484375,56.218923189166624],[-88.59374999999999,56.65622649350222],[-95.185546875,52.9751081817353],[-95.00976562499999,49.36806633482156],[-94.85595703125,49.33944093715546],[-94.658203125,48.850258199721495],[-94.130859375,48.66194284607006],[-93.1201171875,48.63290858589535],[-92.59277343749999,48.48748647988415],[-91.82373046875,48.16608541901253],[-90.87890625,48.122101028190805],[-89.49462890625,48.06339653776211],[-88.1982421875,48.90805939965008],[-86.50634765625,48.719961222646276],[-86.0009765625,48.019324184801185],[-85.078125,47.97521412341618],[-84.39697265625,46.46813299215554],[-83.49609375,46.255846818480315],[-82.1337890625,46.17983040759436],[-80.57373046875,45.72152152227954],[-79.87060546875,44.91813929958515],[-80.1123046875,44.512176171071054],[-81.36474609375,45.19752230305682],[-81.27685546875,44.74673324024678],[-81.73828125,43.58039085560784],[-82.6171875,42.68243539838623],[-82.24365234375,42.32606244456202],[-79.82666015625,43.35713822211053],[-76.5087890625,44.18220395771566],[-75.03662109375,44.933696389694674],[-73.916015625,45.3521452458518],[-74.53125,45.644768217751924],[-75.78369140625,45.398449976304086],[-78.64013671875,46.36209301204985],[-79.5849609375,47.62097541515849],[-79.453125,51.42661449707482],[-81.73828125,52.696361078274485],[-82.353515625,55.178867663281984],[-84.19921875,55.02802211299252],[-86.923828125,55.92458580482951],[-95.80078125,60.108670463036],[-101.513671875,60.23981116999893],[-101.337890625,64.24459476798195],[-108.544921875,64.8115572502203],[-109.51171875,65.5129625532949],[-112.8515625,65.6582745198266],[-120.58593749999999,67.84241647327927],[-120.673828125,69.56522590149099],[-116.3671875,68.942606818121],[-115.31249999999999,68.10610151896537],[-110.12695312499999,68.10610151896537],[-107.666015625,66.65297740055279],[-106.61132812499999,68.366801093914],[-104.4140625,67.97463396204759],[-98.0859375,67.84241647327927],[-96.064453125,67.06743335108298],[-95.2734375,68.10610151896537],[-93.07617187499999,69.00567519658819],[-91.40625,69.31832006949072],[-89.6484375,69.25614923150721],[-87.099609375,67.2720426739952],[-85.4296875,68.65655498475735],[-84.19921875,69.7485511291223],[-82.177734375,68.6885206018014],[-81.2109375,67.44122869796351],[-83.232421875,66.5482634621744],[-86.044921875,66.37275500247455],[-86.8359375,65.14611484756372],[-92.548828125,62.67414334669093],[-95.09765625,60.23981116999893],[-87.71484375,56.218923189166624]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Region2"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-79.013671875,51.45400691005982],[-79.365234375,47.635783590864854],[-78.31054687499999,46.437856895024204],[-75.76171875,45.644768217751924],[-74.35546875,45.89000815866184],[-71.103515625,47.100044694025215],[-66.796875,50.17689812200107],[-62.84179687499999,50.3454604086048],[-56.953125,51.56341232867588],[-63.19335937499999,52.26815737376817],[-63.80859374999999,52.74959372674114],[-64.248046875,51.890053935216926],[-66.181640625,52.908902047770255],[-67.5,54.36775852406841],[-66.884765625,54.97761367069628],[-63.369140625,54.62297813269033],[-64.86328125,59.977005492196],[-67.32421875,58.53959476664049],[-69.169921875,58.768200159239576],[-69.9609375,60.973107109199404],[-73.828125,62.431074232920906],[-77.431640625,62.552856958572896],[-78.3984375,58.99531118795094],[-76.2890625,56.26776108757582],[-79.62890625,54.87660665410869],[-78.486328125,52.16045455774706],[-79.013671875,51.45400691005982]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Region1"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-64.775390625,60.261617082844616],[-63.32519531249999,54.635697306063854],[-66.86279296875,54.96500166110205],[-67.4560546875,54.34214886448341],[-66.07177734375,52.93539665862318],[-64.35791015625,51.97134580885172],[-63.87451171875,52.84259457223949],[-63.21533203124999,52.38901106223458],[-56.84326171875,51.6180165487737],[-55.7666015625,52.14697334064471],[-55.8984375,53.396432127095984],[-57.10693359375,53.8265967429941],[-57.94189453125,54.34214886448341],[-57.23876953124999,54.62297813269033],[-59.08447265624999,54.99022172004893],[-60.1171875,55.32914440840507],[-60.53466796874999,55.81362907119958],[-61.25976562499999,56.30434864830831],[-61.39160156249999,56.90900226702048],[-61.962890625,57.903174456371474],[-64.70947265625,60.48970392643919],[-64.775390625,60.261617082844616]]]}}]}
```

This is the data we have used in our project.

```
count,Row Labels,Age,Dea,Episode_week,Recv,Region,Recovered
1,1059,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,4716,6,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,5931,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,6778,6,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,6814,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,6979,6,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,7632,3,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,8842,3,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,8856,1,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,10639,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,11394,1,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,11558,3,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,12600,5,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,13105,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,13196,3,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,13318,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,13583,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,14811,5,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,14864,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,14939,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,15445,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,17313,5,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,19115,6,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,19970,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,20773,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,21446,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,21522,5,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,21543,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,22133,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,23536,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,23699,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,23830,3,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,25580,3,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,26213,1,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,26412,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,27032,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,28321,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,30678,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,30982,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,31764,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,31944,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,34577,6,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,36047,1,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,37365,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,9,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,171,4,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,432,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,730,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,968,1,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,1282,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,1491,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,1751,6,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,2016,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,2214,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,2515,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,2790,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,3002,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,3265,3,0,8,1,Region4,1
1,3618,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,3877,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,4082,6,0,8,0,Region3,0
1,4370,2,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,4580,99,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,4764,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,5044,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,5258,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,5517,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,5786,2,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,6238,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,6476,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,6740,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,6936,6,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,7208,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,7482,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,7818,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,8097,2,0,8,0,Region3,0
1,8307,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,8500,6,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,8701,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,8896,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,9070,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,9314,5,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,9502,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,9777,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,9933,6,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,10137,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,10388,6,1,8,0,Region3,2
1,10582,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,10831,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,11054,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,11268,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,11483,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,11721,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,11983,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,12231,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,12483,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,12689,7,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,12844,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,13081,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,13298,5,0,8,0,Region3,0
1,13472,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,13713,4,0,8,1,Region4,1
1,13988,5,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,14105,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,14353,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,14715,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,14961,3,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,15172,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,15437,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,15678,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,15873,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,16159,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,16450,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,16733,2,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,16916,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,17200,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,17427,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,17713,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,17906,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,18132,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,18378,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,18556,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,18758,7,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,19016,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,19241,1,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,19429,6,0,8,0,Region3,0
1,19771,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,20055,99,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,20169,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,20325,4,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,20546,7,0,8,1,Region4,1
1,20904,4,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,21093,7,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,21312,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,21492,3,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,21722,6,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,21988,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,22173,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,22407,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,22613,99,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,22831,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,22987,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,23276,4,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,23539,8,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,23788,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,24085,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,24273,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,24509,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,24726,8,1,8,0,Region3,2
1,24878,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,25073,2,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,25268,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,25541,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,25746,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,25983,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,26236,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,26353,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,26497,2,0,8,1,Region4,1
1,26685,6,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,26892,4,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,27142,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,27341,4,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,27646,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,27945,5,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,28127,3,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,28405,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,28636,6,0,8,1,Region4,1
1,28838,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,28995,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,29280,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,29616,2,0,8,0,Region3,0
1,29808,5,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,30096,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,30446,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,30637,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,30881,3,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,31183,5,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,31469,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,31723,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,31939,4,0,8,0,Region5,0
1,32100,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,32441,4,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,32787,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,33069,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,33294,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,33506,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,33690,5,0,8,1,Region3,1
1,34093,7,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,34406,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,34608,2,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,34784,8,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,35057,7,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,35315,8,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,35504,1,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,35744,3,0,8,1,Region5,1
1,35918,6,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,36150,6,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,36406,6,0,8,1,Region1,1
1,36668,7,1,8,0,Region2,2
1,36938,2,0,8,1,Region2,1
1,37191,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,37407,8,0,8,0,Region2,0
1,108,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,414,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,577,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,727,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,788,3,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,1010,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,1305,8,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,1525,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,1860,2,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,1944,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,2380,3,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,2628,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,2637,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,2927,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,3991,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,4202,3,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,4305,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,4423,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,4774,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,4831,2,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,4987,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,5225,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,5352,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,5396,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,5443,2,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,5505,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,5598,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,6043,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,6654,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,6763,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,6864,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,6975,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,7640,7,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,7642,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,8546,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,8776,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,9036,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,9130,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,9423,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,10408,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,10511,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,10773,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,12244,3,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,12453,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,13473,5,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,13512,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,13659,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,15397,3,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,15734,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,15810,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,16153,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,16270,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,16370,2,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,16919,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,16955,6,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,16974,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,16983,2,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,17069,7,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,17143,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,17841,2,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,18053,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,18198,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,18238,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,18363,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,18657,3,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,18700,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,18711,4,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,19263,7,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,19440,7,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,19665,3,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,19698,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,19749,5,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,20206,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,20842,99,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,20975,4,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,21142,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,21386,3,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,21519,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,21649,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,22199,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,22401,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,22573,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,22574,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,23329,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,23543,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,23684,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,23976,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,24339,4,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,25592,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,26070,2,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,26238,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,26367,3,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,26410,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,26440,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,26533,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,26582,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,27043,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,27430,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,27452,6,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,27826,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,27969,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,28090,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,28197,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,28598,6,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,28759,5,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,28925,7,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,29744,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,29881,5,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,29936,3,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,30308,6,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,31337,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,31356,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,31408,3,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,31698,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,32270,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,32626,2,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,32864,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,33115,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,33406,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,33450,6,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,33522,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,34238,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,34388,4,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,34500,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,35187,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,35211,5,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,35320,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,35846,3,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,35999,3,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,36010,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,36015,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,36039,4,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,36316,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,36602,3,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,36697,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,36851,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,36960,4,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,36995,5,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,37029,3,0,9,0,Region4,0
1,37052,6,0,9,1,Region1,1
1,24,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,207,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,446,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,734,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,975,2,0,9,1,Region1,1
1,1317,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,1495,8,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,1752,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,2019,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,2215,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,2520,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,2809,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,3010,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,3308,7,1,9,0,Region4,2
1,3635,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,3885,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,4092,2,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,4380,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,4606,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,4790,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,5068,1,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,5303,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,5535,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,5826,8,0,9,1,Region1,1
1,6248,7,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,6483,4,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,6745,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,6940,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,7210,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,7495,5,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,7823,7,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,8106,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,8312,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,8544,7,1,9,0,Region4,2
1,8708,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,8904,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,9083,5,0,9,1,Region1,1
1,9331,5,0,9,0,Region5,0
1,9504,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,9779,2,0,9,1,Region4,1
1,9972,6,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,10178,5,0,9,1,Region1,1
1,10403,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,10597,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,10882,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,11058,5,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,11296,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,11505,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,11728,2,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,12001,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,12241,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,12486,3,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,12690,2,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,12891,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,13086,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,13305,5,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,13483,8,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,13718,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,13993,1,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,14118,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,14362,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,14721,2,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,14978,7,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,15188,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,15440,7,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,15689,8,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,15907,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,16186,6,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,16464,1,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,16735,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,16917,8,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,17210,4,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,17431,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,17723,6,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,17916,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,18134,8,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,18394,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,18573,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,18759,7,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,19026,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,19248,7,1,9,0,Region3,2
1,19447,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,19785,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,20057,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,20183,6,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,20343,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,20554,4,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,20912,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,21095,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,21315,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,21514,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,21726,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,21993,6,0,9,1,Region3,1
1,22188,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,22410,2,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,22620,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,22873,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,22989,4,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,23292,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,23546,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,23793,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,24087,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,24275,6,0,9,0,Region3,0
1,24517,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,24733,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,24886,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,25097,7,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,25289,2,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,25550,2,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,25751,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,26007,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,26244,7,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,26358,2,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,26505,8,1,9,0,Region2,2
1,26720,7,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,26894,2,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,27147,5,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,27350,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,27668,4,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,27950,8,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,28185,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,28407,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,28644,3,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,28842,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,29047,8,0,9,0,Region2,0
1,29315,8,0,9,1,Region2,1
1,29627,4,0,9,1,Region5,1
1,29809,8,0,9,1,Region5,1
```

Comment: Can you please share the source of your geojson? It might be pre-procesed in a particular way (scaled, translated) or unprojected.

Comment: Your geojson looks correct according to a couple of online lint / test sites. I just tried for an hour or so but couldn't figure out why it is not displaying. Will try again soon. For the moment, please edit your question and add an excerpt of your data, so that the question is complete in itself. SO guidelines ask not to refer to sources outside the site, and those links aren't public.

Comment: Thanq Gordon!!! Hope you can help me by coming up with some positive reply.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your map isn't displaying correctly is most likely down to the projection settings.

Personally, I find the easiest way to get everything lined up is to use a website like [Mapstarter](http://mapstarter.com/) to handle the pre-processing of your geo files. For Canada, you can use conic equal area with your chosen width and height. I used provinces, but you can adapt it to regions or to any other level.

I paired the sample Canada `.topojson` from mapstarter with a basic `.csv` that looks like this:

```
NAME             CODE NUMBER
Alberta          CA01 3
British Columbia CA02 5
Manitoba         CA03 10
...
```

Then, your `DC.js` code will look something like this:

```
async function getData() {

    const viz = {};
  
    const csvDataPromise = d3.csv("data/data.csv");
    const jsonDataPromise = d3.json("data/canada.topojson");
  
    viz.csvData = await csvDataPromise;
    viz.jsonData = await jsonDataPromise;
  
    return viz;
  
}

getData()
  .then((viz) => {

  const mapChart = new dc.GeoChoroplethChart("#map");

  const xdata = crossfilter(viz.csvData);
  const provinces = xdata.dimension(d => d.CODE);
  const values = provinces.group().reduceSum(d => d.NUMBER);

  const width = 600;
  const height = 600;

  const featureCollection = topojson.feature(viz.jsonData, viz.jsonData.objects.collection);
  // the test numbers were randomly generated from 0-10 range
  const normalize = function(val, min=0, max=10) { return (val - min) / (max - min); }

  const projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
    .parallels([49,77])
    .rotate([91.86667, 0])
    .fitSize([width, height], featureCollection);

  mapChart
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .dimension(provinces)
    .projection(projection)
    .group(values)
    .overlayGeoJson(featureCollection.features, "provinces", d => d.properties.CODE)  
    .colors(d3.interpolateRdPu)
    .colorCalculator(d => d ? mapChart.colors()(normalize(d)) : "#ccc")
    .title(function(r) {
      let nameArray = viz.csvData.filter(d => {if (d.CODE === r.key) { return d; }});
      return `${nameArray[0].NAME}: ${r.value}`
  });

  mapChart.render();

  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

[image]

The key thing about this specific type of projection is that you need to set the parallels and rotation. This information is usually included by the publishers of raw geo files (`.prj` file in case of ESRI shapefile folder). You also need to watch out for the name of the object that contains geometry as different sources will name it differently. Here it's called "collection" as in `jsonData.objects.collection`.

Comment: Agree, I think there was something weird about their geojson that makes it incompatible with d3/dc. I tried a lot of projections and it either covered the whole globe or I got just a tiny splotch. And yeah, any linear interpolated color scale should work. GeoChoropleth has not gotten as much love and care as the rest of dc.js

Comment: Thanq gherka and gordan. I m going to take your inputs and work back

Comment: Thank you  gherka and Gordon. We made it with your help finally!